# Laravel画像を投稿

Tags: php, laravel, 画像

私はLaravelで画像を投稿出来るようにしたい

その際のコードはこれです
**view**

```
<form>
 <input type="file" name="imagefile" accept="image/*">
 <input type="text" name="content">
</form>
```

しかしその後コントローラー側で画像の保存方法が調べても分からない
上手くできたのはシンボリックリンクだけです

```
$post_data = $request->except('imagefile');
$imagefile = $request->file('imagefile');
$temp_path = $imagefile->store('public/temp');

$a = new Test;
$a->fill($request->all())->save();
```

この様な処理をしても

> imagefileにNULLは入れることは出来ません

と出てきて処理が悪いのはわかるのですが何をしたらいいのかは思いつ来ませんでした

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59098084/i-want-to-post-images-on-laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

この方法で無事画像の保存が上手くできました

```
$post_data = $request->except('imagefile');
$imagefile = $request->file('imagefile');
$temp_path = $imagefile->store('public/temp');
$filename = $request->file('image');
$post_data->imagefile = $filename;

$a = new Test;
$a->fill($post_data)->save();
```

[元の質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59098084/i-want-to-post-images-on-laravel) 
[回答者](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11790356/vikas-katariya)

Comment: [英語版でのあなたの質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59098084) における、他のユーザからの回答を参考にしたのであれば、その事がわかるようにこの回答にもリンクを含めましょう。出典を明記して、手助けしてくれた人へのリスペクトを忘れないようにしましょう。- ご参考: [表示が必要 (Attribution Required)](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2940)

Comment: @cubick  分かりましたありがとうございます